# Python: Creating folders based on ID3 Tags

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, directory, mutagen

I am trying to figure out how I can create  directories based on the ID3 tags extracted from the mp3 files in this order Artist>Album> ( here need to be the actual .mp3 file)?

So far my ID3 Tags are stored in pandas dataframe and I have made a directory for the first artist. Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
from mutagen.easyid3 import EasyID3
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
import pathlib
import os

def createFolder(directory):
try:
    os.makedirs(directory)

except OSError:
    print ('Error: Creating directory. ' +  directory)
def createArtist(df,path):
    artist_list = list(df.artist)
    for i in artist_list:

        os.makedirs(path+str(i))
        artist_df = df.loc[df['artist'] == i]
audio = MP3("Skepta - Shutdown.mp3", ID3=EasyID3)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = audio.keys())
a = (list(pathlib.Path('H:/').glob('*.mp3')))
createFolder('./Music Library/')

###this updates the dataframe with ID3 tags for each .mp3 file in H:/

for i in range(1,len(a)):
    audio=MP3(a[i],ID3=EasyID3)
    df.loc[i] = audio.values()
    print(df)
path ='/Music Library/'      
createArtist(df,path)
```